# SQL Server BULK INSERT problems with ROWTERMINATOR

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm working on SQL Server BULK INSERT process for multiple files into multiple tables.
I've run into difficulty with my very first file.

My raw text file looks like this:

```
Date | Name | ID | Comment
11/11/2016 10:25:29 | Fake Name1 | aa12345 | Fake comment - stuff
14/11/2016 10:43:22 | Fake Name2 | bb23456 | Fake comment - stuff
14/11/2016 12:06:40 | Fake Name3 | cc34567 | Fake comment - stuff
15/11/2016 10:38:33 | Fake Name4 | dd45678 | Fake comment - stuff
```

My SQL statement like so:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.[FakeTable]
FROM '...\FakeTextFile.txt'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ' | ',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
    TABLOCK,
    KEEPNULLS
)
```

Like this, the statement executes without error but fails to insert any records into the table. I added an ERRORFILE argument to try to capture the problem but no error output was returned:

```
ERRORFILE = '...\Fake_error.txt'
```

Made various alterations to the ROWTERMINATOR argument ('0x0a', '0x0d', '0x0a0x0d', '0x0d0x0a', 'CHAR(10)', 'CHAR(13)', 'CHAR(10)CHAR(13)', 'CHAR(13)CHAR(10)', '\r\n', '\n\r'). For most of these configurations, the statement executed without error but also without successfully inserting any rows into the table (0 rows affected).

Found that for '0x0a', '0x0d' and '\n' (note single backslash char), the statement inserted the first specified row into the table as expected but returned errors for all subsequent rows in the text file:

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 1 (Date).
```

Because this comprises part of a wider automated solution, the use of FORMATFILE is not practical if it can be avoided (multiple files, tables; single execution).

Given the data is of the same type in all rows, I suspect that the problem is somehow with the ROWTERMINATOR argument.

I have attempted the introduction of various CODEPAGE and DATAFILETYPE argument configurations but to no avail.

I'd very much appreciate any insights that might help to resolve this problem.
Thanks for looking.

**UPDATE:**
Created a format file (XML) like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="|" MAX_LENGTH="20"/>
<FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="|" MAX_LENGTH="4000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="|" MAX_LENGTH="4000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="4000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
</RECORD>
<ROW>
<COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Date" xsi:type="SQLDATE"/>
<COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Name" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
<COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="ID" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
<COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Comment" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Sadly, execution using this format file yielded the same result:

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 1 (Date).
```

Comment: Can one assume correctly that you've opened the file in a hex editor to see whether or not it starts with any byte order mark/preamble sequence, what character encoding the file uses and what the actual linebreak character(s) might be?

Comment: Yes; should also have added this to original question narrative. I opened in Notepad++ and can clearly see carriage return and line feed characters at end of each line. Additionally, adding the FIELDTERMINATOR (' | ') to the end of line, before the LF/CR does not change anything.

Comment: `executes without error but fails to insert any records` I doubt it. How is the statement executed? Directly in an admin tool like SSMS or Azure Data Studio? Or through an application that may not be logging the errors?

Comment: Executed directly in SSMS. 
Errors returned for subsequent rows when the first row is successfully inserted; no errors when no rows inserted.

Comment: `this comprises part of a wider automated solution, the use of FORMATFILE is not practical` that assumption is wrong. SQL Server has ETL tools since the 1990s and the T part, Transformation, is fundamental in all data automation jobs. In fact, given the *localized* dates, a FORMATFILE is definitely needed

Comment: Executed directly and what happens? What is shown in the messages tab? Are you using a transaction?  What do you get if you run `SELECT * FROM dbo.[FakeTable]` right after `BULK INSERT`, in the same window?

Comment: Since the ingestion part is always so difficult, I suggest bulk inserting into a table whose datatypes are all `VARCHAR(8000)` or similiar, then have a post import step (i.e. a stored proc) that runs DQ checks and puts the file into the final table (often an incremental import is required, so it makes even more sense to do this)

Comment: In any case, given the localized date format, it's better to use SSIS to import the data as a flat file and convert the strings to proper dates. The SSIS wizard (and designers) allow you to inspect the data and see what using different options will do. It's quite possible that the row terminator is *not* what you assume.

Comment: Why should a format file definitely be needed? The use of a format file for bulk insert is optional, no?

Comment: It would probably clarify things if you posted the DDL of the target table. If the `Date` column is of type datetime. then you need some step to convert the data you have into a datetime that is recognised. This could be a format file or it could be a post import DQ stored procedure or it could be SSIS

Comment: Because the file doesn't use an ISO8601 date. That *string* can't be converted to a correct `date` without specifying the format - or using an unambiguous format like `YYYY-MM-DD`. Without a format file, you may end up loading the wrong dates

Comment: Try loading the file using SSMS's Flat File or Import Data wizards to see what's going on, what the correct settings are. This way you can verify whether your assumptions are correct at least

Comment: No transaction; I'm just developing this process so the statement is being executed directly in SSMS as shown above.
The message tab contains '0 row(s) affected' when no rows are inserted and no error is returned. When the first specified row is inserted (with ROWTERMINATOR '\n'), the message tab  shows the error detailed above, followed by '1 row(s) affected'.

Comment: Given the behavior you describe it sounds to me like the source file is UCS2 or UTF-16 encoded. Are you sure you opened the hex editor plugin in Notepad++ and saw the first line report exactly as `00000000 44 61 74 65 20 7C 20 4E 61 6D 65 20 7C 20 49 44  Date | Name | ID`? There were no extra bytes before `Date` and there weren't `00` bytes between each character?

Comment: Okay. So you reckon the ROWTERMINATOR argument is not the issue but the date format?
It is true that the date in the text file (first row) is in 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM:ss' format; the date in the single row inserted into the table appears in 'yyyy-MM-dd  hh:MM:ss.mmm' format. So I guess this makes sense and some method of conversion is in order as suggested.

Comment: It is likely the date causing the issue. Note: 1. There is no indicator whether the date in your file is dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy. That's why you _may_ need a format file for. 2. The data format you see in SSMS just happens to the format it renders it in. In fact behind the scenes, the data in the table is an unambiguous "Datetime" with no format. 3. I recommend VSCode over Notepad++

Comment: There are a lot of pieces to solving this, especially if you are hoping to build a larger scale automated ingestion solution. 1. Do you have control over the format of data exported? 2. Are you required to load incremental files? 3. How are you handling data quality checks and import failures? Note I can reproduce your error and one way to fix it is to change date format in the file to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. This confirms dates are the issue but probably isn't a good solution for you

Comment: Looking at the doco, you just want `\r` for CRLF rowterminator , not `\r\n`. Aftre this you need to solve the datetime format issue

Comment: *.csv/txt flat files always have host of problems where column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data. Or data elements are missing completely.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML enforced by an XSD. An XSD plays a role of a data contract between sender and receiver. It will guarantee proper data format/shape, data types, cardinality, and enforce data quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fiddling with both XML and traditional format files, without success, I started to examine the actual values I was attempting to insert more closely.

From my raw data  file, the first row with the date '11/11/2016 10:25:29' inserted successfully; the problems began with the second and subsequent rows (dates '14/11/2016 10:43:22', '14/11/2016 12:06:40', '15/11/2016 10:38:33').

```
SELECT CAST('11/11/2016 10:25:29' AS DateTime)
```

... resolves correctly and returns '2016-11-11 10:25:29.000'.

BUT...

```
SELECT CAST('14/11/2016 10:43:22' AS DateTime)
```

... returns error:
'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

In the end, it was just the simple but very annoying 'dd/mm/yyyy' vs. 'mm/dd/yyyy' date format.

Reworked the process outputting the text files to correct the date format and bulk insert process works fine (no format file required).

Thanks all for time and insights.

Comment: Yes as per various comments, assuming you have control over the data exported, you should always use ISO format for dates. You should be able to accept your answer.